# issue in fetching the record in page from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have record like `<p>good video"<strong>good</strong>"</p>` in database(mysql).
But if I am trying to fetch the record from database to my webpage(based on php). It is showing but the word `good`  is showing with a normal font, not in bold font.
My code is like:

```
$gallerycontent = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT content FROM cms WHERE cms_id=27"));
echo $gallerycontent['content'];
```

Please help me how to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you watched the exact query result string? Also, I recommend trying another tag, like "h1" to see if it actually works.

Comment: remove the quotes <p>good video<strong>good</strong></p>

Comment: i dont think that it is not working. whether in ``""`` or alone, ``strong`` should work. can you pls show us your frotendsite?

Comment: @Ismet Alkan its not working for h1 tag also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ensure that the `strong` tags are appearing in the rendered source.

If they are there then you likely need to set the css style to make them appear bold.

```
strong {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Ya its fine, but the same thing is happening for list style. Bulleting option are not showing.

Comment: This is likely a css issue but without seeing your site it is hard to say.  Could you please provide a link to your project?

Answer (score 0):

You are already making it as string `"<strong>good</strong>"`. Remove quotes like that:

```
<p>good video<strong>good</strong></p>
```

And then it will work good, or you can remove quotes like that:

```
$gallerycontent['content'] = str_replace(""", '', $gallerycontent['content']);
echo $gallerycontent['content'];
```

Output will be:

> good video **good**